# Angular material form input box styling not displaying properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I came accross a form wizard by Afrad on github [material-wizard](https://github.com/Matesign/material-wizard) and will like to implement it because of its angular-material properties. The downside is that the text-boxes turn out totally different from the angular styling. Is there a way to fix this? what causes this and how do you go about the fix. I have tried using ngWizard as well and face the same issue. the forms display okay without being encapsulated in the wizard directive.
A link to a plunker showing the demo is on the github page. Attached below is a snapshot of the plunker.
[image]

Comment: post the plunker link

Comment: It looks like Angular Material is not loaded. These are the files you need - https://github.com/angular/material/tree/v1.1.0-rc.5#cdn

Comment: @Camden_kid: I have only that I have newer versions of them. regardless of that, its included inside the plunker but the same issue occurs there too like in the snapshot.

Comment: @Camden_kid: Note that i mentioned that the forms display well outside the wizard directive and only render abnormally when inside. I inspected elements and found out the input boxes revert to the default without css applied. just couldn't figure out whats the cause.

Comment: @Camden_kid: works in Angular v1.3 but not in v1.5